# Java equivalent to MD5CryptoServiceProvider computeHash & ToBase64String

Tags: java, c#, encryption, cryptography

I compute MD5 hash for a string in C# the following way:

```
var provider = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
var bytes= Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value);
bytes = provider.ComputeHash(bytes);
return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

I need to do the same calculation in Java (Android) to match the hash produced using the above method. I tried the following with no luck:

1.

```
byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(str.getBytes());
return new String(encoded);
```

2.

```
String digest = null;

MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] hash = md.digest(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));

//converting byte array to Hexadecimal String
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(2*hash.length);
for(byte b : hash){
    sb.append(String.format("%02x", b&0xff));
}

digest = sb.toString();
```

3.

```
String resultHash = null;
    try {
        MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

        byte[] result = new byte[md5.getDigestLength()];
        md5.reset();
        md5.update(buffer);
        result = md5.digest();

        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(result.length * 2);

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            int intVal = result[i] & 0xff;
            if (intVal < 0x10) {
                buf.append("0");
            }
            buf.append(Integer.toHexString(intVal));
        }

        resultHash = buf.toString();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    }
    return resultHash;
```

**EDIT:**

The Objective C method that produced the C# matching values is this:

```
NSMutableString *encodedData = [NSMutableString string];

int i = 0, j = 0;

unsigned char char_array_3[3];

unsigned char char_array_4[5];



memset(char_array_3, 0, 3*sizeof(char));

memset(char_array_4, 0, 5*sizeof(char));



int length = [md5Data length];

char *bytes = (char*)[md5Data bytes];



while(length--) {

    char_array_3[i++] = *(bytes++);

    if (i == 3) {

        char_array_4[0] = kBase64Alphabet[(char_array_3[0] & 0xfc)>>2];

        char_array_4[1] = kBase64Alphabet[((char_array_3[0] &

                                            0x03) <<4) + ((char_array_3[1] & 0xf0) >>4)];

        char_array_4[2] = kBase64Alphabet[((char_array_3[1] &

                                            0x0f) <<2) + ((char_array_3[2] & 0xc0) >>6)];

        char_array_4[3] = kBase64Alphabet[char_array_3[2]&0x3f];



        [encodedData appendString:[NSString

                                   stringWithUTF8String:(const char*)char_array_4]];



        i = 0;

    }

}



if (i) {

    for(j=i; j<3; j++)

        char_array_3[j] = '\0';



    char_array_4[0] = kBase64Alphabet[(char_array_3[0] & 0xfc)>>2];

    char_array_4[1] = kBase64Alphabet[((char_array_3[0] & 0x03)

                                       <<4) + ((char_array_3[1] & 0xf0) >>4)];

    char_array_4[2] = kBase64Alphabet[((char_array_3[1] & 0x0f)

                                       <<2) + ((char_array_3[2] & 0xc0) >>6)];

    char_array_4[3] = kBase64Alphabet[char_array_3[2]&0x3f];



    char_array_4[i+1] = 0;

    [encodedData appendString:[NSString

                               stringWithUTF8String:(const char*)char_array_4]];



    while((i++<3))

        [encodedData appendString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:"="]];

    }



    return encodedData;

}
```

**Example**

```
 `wattlebird` in C# -> `ixfbWnWq9QmLecMFCzaZcw==`
 `wattlebird` in java -> `GTd5lE58tKIlpdmppEVurw==`
```

Comment: Your main problem is that Encoding.Unicode in C# means UTF-16 in little endian, not UTF-8 what you use.

Comment: Do you understand what each of these code snippets does, or did you just copy-paste code and hope it works?

Comment: My understanding is very limited in this area.

Comment: @Robert thanks, it worked, I did just: `str.getBytes("UTF-16LE")` instead of `str.getBytes("UTF-8")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) != [Hex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal). You can use [`Base64`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) from [apache commons-codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/),

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

// ...

public static String hashValue(String value) {
    String digest = null;
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] hash = md.digest(value.getBytes("UTF-16LE")); // <-- note encoding
        return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(hash));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Still not a match. If I encrypt the word `wattlebird` in C# and get `ixfbWnWq9QmLecMFCzaZcw==`, in java I get `GTd5lE58tKIlpdmppEVurw==`

Comment: If he's using android he doesn't need to use an external library since android has built in Base64 support

Comment: GTd5lE58tKIlpdmppEVurw== is the exact value I got using Java 8's Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hash). I don't really have apache-commons-codec ready right now, but I would be surprised if encodeBase64String didn't do exactly the same thing as the Java 8 equivalent.

Comment: @fremmedehenvendelser `GTd5lE58tKIlpdmppEVurw==` is the correct answer your value is wrong

Comment: @dkatzel Thanks, but please, see the C# code in the very beginning of the question, what I'm looking for is the Java way of producing the same output as does the that code.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch: Encoding.Unicode in C# is effectively UTF-16 (Little-Endian) not UTF-8.

Comment: @Robert Edited, [*great* catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.unicodeencoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)!

Comment: Of course, good catch! By the way, I do hope that MD5 isn't being used for anything security-related.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It should probably be "UTF-16LE" instead of "UTF-16" – the latter inserts a BOM if I remember correctly.

Comment: Thanks, the encoding was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Base64 is not just the values of the bytes in hex. (here is the RFC spec for how to encode in Base64 [RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648) )

Android has a build in class to work with Base64 encoding `android.util.Base64`

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] hash = md.digest(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));

String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(hash, Base64.DEFAULT);
```